# data format in R using seq()

Tags: r, seq

The R code and error is showing below:

```
> x = seq(0,1,by=0.2)
> stopifnot( x == c(0.0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0))
Error: x == c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1) are not all TRUE
```

I'm a new learn of R and cannot figure out why, can somebody help, thank you!

Comment: Since `all.equal(seq(0,1,by=0.2), c(0.0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0))` returns `TRUE`, I'm assuming it's a floating point representation issue.

Comment: To see the problem: `print(rbind(seq(0,1,by=0.2), c(0.0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0)), digits = 22)`